# Paypal not working in Magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, upgrade, paypal-express

I upgrade my Magento version from 2.2.2 to 2.3.2.

Now PayPal is not working.

Comment: Do you have any custom modules?

Comment: No, I have not any module for PayPal. I used core functionality.

Comment: You should provide more details. Everybody can know how to get the bug.

Comment: Sir, before upgrading the version PayPal working properly. After upgrading, I have set all credential in Magento admin grid same as before version. But PayPal-express not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In paypal Expres Configuration: 
please Disable "In-Context Checkout Experience" it's working properly. I m having the same issue and after disabling its working.

Comment: First, let me check.

Comment: Yes, it's working after disable. Thank you so much.

Comment: Any solutions on this? In Magento 2.3.5-p1 Paypal In-Context Checkout still doesn't work.

Comment: @KaMZaTa did you ever find a proper solution?

Comment: @YorkieMagento I upgraded to 2.4.0 but I didn't check yet if now it works.